# Native nested CSS selectors with :host()

Tags: css

Now that nested CSS selectors are becoming more maintstream in browsers,

How would one convert this to use nested CSS selectors:

```css
:host {
    color:red;
    &:hover {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

The above does not work because I think it needs `:host(:hover)`.
I tried `&(:hover)` but it did not work.

Was so excited for nested selectors, but since most of my styling is in web components, it makes them pretty much useless.

To make it explicit, this is **NOT** using a preprocessor like LESS or SASS.

Comment: `:host` and `:host()` are two different selectors (the latter [is a function](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scoping-1/#host-selector)) so I guess nesting them that way is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @InSync Yes I wasn't too hopeful when I tried it, just tried everything I could think of before resorting to SO